# Output intent set to fogra39, but looking in preflight in Acrobat says intent is Fogra27?

Tags: print-production, color-profile

This is a follow-up question on the comments here: [What happens if a commercial printer is using another profile than a file sent to be printed is converted to?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/156811/170242)

I made a print-ready PDF and dug inside Acrobat to see what it has eaten. I have made the output intent fogra39 in the export and am sure of this. When I open the file in Acrobat, it views the output intent on fogra39 as automatically.

If I go to the preflight PDF analysis part it says output intent FOGRA27 and in the info part Fogra39 (see screenshot). This looks weird to me since Fogra27 is a different profile?

Is this just a glitch and/or normal, and the intent is fogra39 as it should be?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Since you are so interested in PDF internals have you checked what the pdf spec says about what identifiers mean?

Comment: I tried searching around this subject but didn’t find anything that was understandable for my level of knowledge. If you can point me some further reading, I will do that. I simply made some tests with different export settings and was looking into what effects they have and then bumped into this.

Comment: This seems that Indesign automatically adds this information. If I don't touch the intent at all (it goes there automatically with certain settings) the identifier field is empty, but FOGRA27 appears as identifier name in preflight. If I manually select fogra39 as intent, it will appear also in indesign output identifier name. If I then remove the text, preflight output condition identifier is FOGRA39. So to me, this looks like an error.

Comment: Identifier is probably a arbitrary name. And since 39 replaces 27 they probably just let the id stay the same since its the same anyway.

Comment: You are propably right and maybe I am looking too deep while trying to learn. As a sidenote still, looks like an error of some kind since when I manually remove the automatically appearing name, it gets fixed (it turns to all fogra39 in preflight). Out of curiosity I tried to do the same kind of export on Illustrator, also no fogra27 appearing anywhere in there.

Comment: thats because fogra 27 is now fogra 39